# Code for reading a .dat file gives indexing error

Tags: matlab, file, raw-data

I have a source code that is supposed to read a .dat file. the code is in Matlab. There is an error I am getting every time I try to read a .dat file:

This is the .dat file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iQM4P__FQqLCvHHdvkLwbo-jhHNNRXAl/view

> Error using zeros
>
> Size inputs must be integers.
>
> Error in readBasebandFile (line 49)
>
> hdrMat = zeros(numFrames, NumHdrs);

```
function [ hdrMat, FrameMat ] = readBasebandFile( file )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

NumHdrs = 6;

fid = fopen(file, 'rb');
if fid < 3
disp(['couldnt read file ' file]);
return
end

f = dir(file);
fsize = f.bytes;

% read first frame
ctr = 0;
hdrMat = [];
FrameMat = [];

while (1)
if feof(fid)
    break
end

% read header
%frame counter
frameCtr = fread(fid, 1,'uint32');
numBins = fread(fid, 1,'uint32');
binLength = fread(fid, 1,'single');
% sampling frequency which defines the range resolution through
% binLength = C/Fs/2, where C is the speed of light in the medium. 
Fs = fread(fid, 1,'single');
% carrier frequency
Fc = fread(fid, 1,'single');
RangeOffset = fread(fid, 1, 'single');

% check valid header read
if isempty(frameCtr) || isempty(numBins) || isempty(binLength) || isempty(Fs) ... 
        || isempty(Fc) || isempty(RangeOffset)
    break;
end

% read data
data = fread(fid, 2*numBins, 'single');
if ctr==0
    % 2 because it's complex values and 4 because 'single' is 4 bytes. 
   numFrames = fsize / (4*(NumHdrs + 2*numBins)); 
   hdrMat = zeros(numFrames, NumHdrs);
   FrameMat = zeros(2*numBins, numFrames);
end
ctr = ctr + 1;

hdrMat(ctr,:) = [double(frameCtr) double(numBins) binLength Fs Fc 
RangeOffset];
FrameMat(:,ctr) = data;

end

[n,m] = size(hdrMat);
disp([file ' read. NumFrames=' num2str(n)]);
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: The error message is quite informative here. The `zeros()` function requires integer inputs. In your case, `NumHdrs` is set explicitly to 6, so it must be `numFrames` that is not an integer.

Comment: what should I change ?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
numFrames = fsize / (4*(NumHdrs + 2*numBins));
```

with

```
numFrames = round(fsize / (4*(NumHdrs + 2*numBins)));
```

Alternatively use `ceil` or `floor` instead of `round` depending on what you need.

As the error message indicates, when you initialize an array, your size inputs must be integer. For example, you can have a `2x2` matrix but there is no such thing as `2.1x2.3` matrix. Mathematically illogical.

Comment: After I changed the code, I recieved this error.
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in readBasebandFile (line 55)
    FrameMat(:,ctr) = data;

Comment: Since I don't know what kind of data you are processing I cannot comment on the details. But in principle you have to make sure the row size of `FrameMat` is equal to the size of the `data` vector. Also make sure `data` is a column vector since you are assigning this variable to all rows of `FrameMat` for a given `ctr` column. Read more here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93586-why-do-i-get-the-subscripted-assignment-dimension-mismatch-error-message

Comment: I do not know how I can upload the data file to stack overflow for people to see. do you have a hint of how can I see how many rows in the .dat file

Comment: Try `length(data)` or `size(data)`

Comment: I still could not open the file please find it attached.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SchIf40XM9BIxsa5sfK9k13bh_6G_a8j/view

Comment: what do you mean by (data)?